# Favicon Html not displaying

Tags: html, favicon

The href reaches the correct graphic in the folder. Why is it not displaying the favicon?

favicon
size: 16 x 16.
format: png.

I already tried clearing the cache of my browser, tried in in Google Chrome and Firefox.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/Favicon.png"/>
```